# retry 3 times before throwing up the final error

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-functions, twilio

In my google cloud function, I am trying to send a sms message via twilio by using the following code. I am getting the error **there was an error => Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT**
I would like to retry the following code at least 3 times before final error is thrown. I do not know know how to accomplish this.

```
const twilio = require('twilio');
const accountSid = new MyKeys().AccountSID();
const authToken = new MyKeys().AuthToken();
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
  .create(textMessage)
  .then((msg: any) => {
    console.log('message sent successfully => ' + textMessage.body);
  })
  .catch((smsError: any) =>
    console.log('there was an error => ' + smsError)
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have to retry 3 times. I resolved the issue of error ESOCKETTIMEDOUT by looking into the textmessage. I realized that I was not passing in the "From" phone number correctly and it was empty. Once I fixed that problem, the error ESOCKETTIMEDOUT  went away.

Comment: Hi @doc92606, good work finding the solution! Can you accept your own answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!